# iMac Mid 2011 Bootcamp running slow

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, imac

I have a lab of iMacs (21.5 Mid 2011) that primarily run Windows 7 X64 via Bootcamp. The issue that they have been seeing since installation, is on the Windows side, anything to do with accessing internal network services via Active Directory (printing, network shares) runs incredibly slow. Adobe CS5 products also run slow.

The problem that makes this issue hard to resolve is that the issue occurs on random computers and different times. For example, computer 10 may have the mentioned problem today, but tomorrow morning it may act fine.

So far, I have:

- Disabled the wireless adapter
- Erased the computers, and created a fresh image which was applied to each of them
- Ensured Ethernet Drivers are up to date
- Ensured Boot Camp drivers are installed
- Disabled RDC from Add/Remove Windows Features
- Unbound and Rejoined AD domain
- Network, switch, ports have been checked and no issues found

However, nothing seems to work. When a traditional PC is introduced to the environment, the issues don't appear to persist, so it is something either on the image/computer, or how the image/computer connects to the network/domain.  Interestingly, iMacs in other rooms that are one generation older so not have the issue - it's only on this specific model.

Has anyone come across this issue, and/or could offer any suggestions I could try? If I have not been specific enough, or more information is required, please let me know and I will give you what I can.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have no definitive answer for you, but check to make sure you're running a full duplex connection (ethernet), with at least 100 Mbps port speed. Some Intel NICs circa 2011 like to negotiate to half duplex port speed to save energy, but it obliterates performance. AD is a fairly chatty protocol and could cause lots of ethernet frame collisions. The NIC property page (under device manager) may tell you if it's connected at half duplex or not.